# How can i create a list with React from nested objects?

Tags: reactjs

I have this type of json structure (i know it's look like a messed up package file...):

```
 "react-dom": {
            "name": "react-dom",
            "version": "16.8.6",
            "dependencies": {
                "react": "^16.8.6",
                "loose-envify": {
                    "name": "loose-envify",
                    "version": "1.3.0",
                    "dependencies": {
                        "js-tokens": "^4.0.0"
                    }
                },
                "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
                "prop-types": {
                    "name": "prop-types",
                    "version": "15.7.2",
                    "dependencies": {
                        "loose-envify": {
                            "name": "loose-envify",
                            "version": "1.4.0",
                            "dependencies": {
                                "js-tokens": "^4.0.0"
                            }
                        },
                        "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
                        "react-is": "^16.8.1"
                    }
                },
                "scheduler":{
                    "name": "scheduler",
                    "version": "0.14.0",
                    "dependencies": {
                        "loose-envify": {
                                "name": "loose-envify",
                                "version": "1.4.0",
                                "dependencies": {
                                    "js-tokens": "^4.0.0"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "object-assign": "^4.1.1"
                }
            }
        },
```

The result should be like in here :

[image]

I need to create a list from this structure and later on add button for expand and collapse each "node".

I can figure out how what's wrong... i've set the component as a recursive component but i can't get the recursive value.

Here is the container component

```
import dataObj from '../assets/complex-package.json';
import DependenciesList from '../components/DependenciesList';
export default function Dependencies() {
    
  return (
    <div>
     <DependenciesList items={dataObj}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the view component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export default function DependenciesList({ items }) {

    return (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(items.dependencies).map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index}>{(typeof (items.dependencies[item]) === 'object') ?
                        <DependenciesList items={items.dependencies[item]} /> : (items.dependencies[item].hasOwnProperty('name') 
                        ? items.dependencies[item] : '')}</li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

b.t.w - i don't want to use any library ...

[CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-lake-uzjim?file=/src/components/DependenciesList.js:0-244fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You've not included a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question so I'll just say that using [react-json-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-view) is a great library for rendering JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check hasOwnProperty on a string. And there will be no chance that an object will reach that else cause as ur checking in if typeof is object. I think below code can help if I understood your problem well.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export default function DependenciesList({ items }) {
  const showItem = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(items.dependencies[item]);
    return `${item} ${items.dependencies[item]}`
  }
  return (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(items.dependencies).map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index}>{(typeof (items.dependencies[item]) === 'object') ?
                    <DependenciesList items={items.dependencies[item]} /> : showItem(item)}</li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```